# On button click perform ajax for sending values in forms are in while loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How can I send input values through AJAX on button click? My code is below. Thanks in advance.

```html
while
{ 
  <form class="commentform">
    <input type="hidden" class="proid" name="proid" value="<?=$rr['id']?>">  
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comval" placeholder="Write a comment.." autocomplete="off">
    <button class="btn btn-post" type="button">Post</button>
  </div> 
  </form>
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $(document).on('click', '.btn-post', function(){  
    var thePostID = $(this).val;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'fetch_comments.php',
      data: { postID: thePostID },
      type: 'POST',
      success: function() {
        alert(data);
      }
    });
```

Comment: `val` vs `val()`

Comment: use name instead of id: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955085/getting-sibling-text-input-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the correct method is `$(this).val()`, not just `$(this).val`.

Secondly, you can simplify your code by getting the data from the closest `form` element using `serialize()`. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-post', function() {  
  var $form = $(this).closest('form');
  $.ajax({
    url: 'fetch_comments.php',
    data: $form.serialize(),
    type: 'POST',
    success: function() {
      alert(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form").serialize();
```

Serialize a form to a query string, that could be sent to a server in an Ajax request.

Comment: in while loop i generated many forms. How can i identify the required form?

Comment: It is depending on your click button